# Excluding some columns in R

Tags: r

```
Y.1992.a1   Y.1992.a2   Y.1992.a3   Y.1992.a4   Y.1992.a5   Y.1993.a1   Y.1993.a2   
Y.1993.a3   Y.1993.a4   Y.1993.a5   Y.1994.a1   Y.1994.a2   Y.1994.a3   Y.1994.a4   
Y.1994.a5   Y.1995.a1   Y.1995.a2   Y.1995.a3   Y.1995.a4   Y.1995.a5   Y.1996.a1   
Y.1996.a2   Y.1996.a3   Y.1996.a4   Y.1996.a5   Y.1997.a1   Y.1997.a2   Y.1997.a3   
Y.1997.a4   Y.1997.a5   Y.1998.a1   Y.1998.a2   Y.1998.a3   Y.1998.a4   Y.1998.a5   
Y.1999.a1   Y.1999.a2   Y.1999.a3   Y.1999.a4   Y.1999.a5
```

These are the names of columns in R data set. How can I exclude the columns with a4 and a5 postfix in R? I mean to keep only whole years with a1 to a3 postfixes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data frame is called `d`, try `d[, -grep("a[45]$", names(d))]` (thanks to @hwnd for improved reg exp)

Comment: It is better to write this as `d[, -grep('a[45]$', names(d))]`

Comment: @Thilo the comma is not needed in this case

Comment: @hwnd yes you're right will update the answer thanks :)